# Can I use AnyDesk to create a virtual second display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, anydesk

I have [AnyDesk](https://anydesk.com/en) on an Android device, and was wondering if it was possible to use the device as a remote second monitor instead of a monitor mirror.

That way I could both change the resolution in it to better suit the smaller mobile screen, and at the same time have the flexibility of having two monitors.

Is it possible?

I know anydesk can change between monitors, but from what i know, there is no way to make a "virtual" display on windows without placing capacitors on a dummy VGA cable.

Comment: This question is off-topic here since it is about an Android device. Might be better suited for the [Android Enthusiasts SE](https://android.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Maybe for my case it uses android, but the anydesk client could be on another windows desktop for someone else. I think the question is more about creating the virtual dummy second monitor on PC than about me using an android device

Comment: I think [Spacedesk](https://www.spacedesk.net/) app is most suitable for you to make a real virtual display for Windows 10+using an Android device. 
Windows extended desktop mode also will be fully functional.